# peoplesoft : making search button(magnifying glass) 'required'

Tags: peoplesoft

How to make the search button(magnifying glass symbol) on a page to 'Required' in PeopleSoft? Clicking upon the magnifying glass takes me to subpage where the inputs given in subpage is directed to a field in standard page.
Any ideas would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You want to make a prompt field required? you do it just like you make other fields required: in the record field properties on the 'Edits' tab you tick the 'Required' checkbox